# Java - Condicionantes (10% mayor)

Tags: java, condiciones

Me encuentro preparando un programa y no consigo dar con la formula correcta. Para el rango de una variable tipo short debo poner una condición de si el número que se introduce será pequeño o grande, con el criterio del 10% de su rango. Es decir, para valores menores que el 10% del rango, éste será pequeño. Para valores mayores que el 90% del rango, éste será grande.

Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

```
public class Bloc02Ejer01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Mínimo y máximo valor para un tipo de dato short ");
        System.out.println("Minimo" + "=" + Short.MIN_VALUE + " " +"Máximo" + "="+ Short.MAX_VALUE);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input value: ");
        short input = in.nextShort(); //double input = in.nextDouble();         
       
        
        if (input > 0)
        {
            if (input <1)
            {
                System.out.println("Positive small number");
            }
            else if (input > 1000000)
            {
                System.out.println("Positive large number");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Positive number");
            }
        }
        else if (input < 0)
        {
            if(Math.abs(input)<1)
            {
                System.out.println("Negative small number");
            }
            else if(Math.abs(input)>1000000)
            {
                System.out.println("Negative small number");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Zero");
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega código de lo que has intentado o cerrarán tu pregunta

Comment: Yo entiendo una cosa pero tu código dice otra. Un short va desde -32.768 a 32.767 dando un total de 65.536 números, cuyo 10% es 6.553,6. Entonces desde -32.768 hasta -26.214 son el 10% más pequeño y el resto será grande. Por otro lado en tu código separas entre positivos y negativos y ahí ya me pierdo

Comment: Hola! Toda la parte de los condicionantes es lo que tengo que editar para que cumpla los del 10%